# How can i convert decimal to double for big calculation in Android

Tags: java, android

```
dp=Double.parseDouble(txtDownPayment.getText().toString()); 

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

// here i need to convert decimal to double or any bigger type.

String temp = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(txtDownPayment.getText().toString()));
txtDownPayment.setText(temp);
```

Comment: i don't understand the question, where is the decimal? why can't you just cast it?

Comment: I mean when i assign the value double v=500000000 then my textbox shows 5.0E8 format. so i don't want to display this format.

Comment: I'm confused; you want 500000000 to display as such and not as 5.0E8, So isn't your problem just how to display a double as the desired string? Why the conversion to/from decimal?

Comment: i want it because of i also want to make the calculation on that number... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double doubleValue = new Double(intValue);
```

Comment: `Double.valueOf(intValue)` is more efficient than creating a new Double object.

Comment: I appreciate your reply but its not proper answer for me. thanks.. :-) have a great day...